# Migrating 200M records from source schema to destination schema with transformations

Tags: java, oracle, performance, migration, data-migration

I am working on some migration project where we need to migrate data from legacy system to new system. Each system has its own schema and hence we need transformations as well. Say for example in legacy we have date in yyyy-mm-dd format where as in new we have epoch, same way Legacy system code to New system code etc.,.

One notable things here is 200M records really does not stand on 1 relations, those are 200M logical business object. So each logic business object intern composes of many tables (roughly I could say 10-12 relations with average of 50 records all together for each logical business object)

In our earlier migration we have a spring batch job (multithreaded with 4 threads) running on company infrastructure with 16GB RAM and 4 core CPU taking 5 logical business objects to migrate in 2 second.  Obviously we cannot go with this for this bulk migration.  Looking for alternative like using Parallel execution in PL/SQL procedure or any other means.

We cannot rely on ETL team as time lines does not match with our project deadlines. Is there any efficient way to handle this?

Jagan

Comment: Efficient way to move 200M items of complex data with transforming? Not without understanding your data, your architecture your problem domain and probably a lot of other things. Spring Batch is usually slow with complex data though, so I wouldn't care too much about those timings.

Comment: From architecture stand point we have both the schemas on the same physical data base.  Data is scattered in multiple tables related hierarchically with each other, depth not more than 2.  Destination schema also having the similar set of structure.  Basically we are dealing with Case Management systems, so data relation ship would be like the parent Case entity, it audits, documents, additional info, comment etc. From source schema perspective we are trying to migrate 60% of data and destination system is just emerging system (I could say roughly 8% loaded, rest migraiton has to happen)

Comment: depends, depends ... if you manage to do everything in the db (Oracle, as it seems), you cut out all java process <> db process overhead, if you manage to do it in the sql engine alone you (transformation through views) you cut out the plsq <> sql engine switches. I did very well with transformation views to an extend that I got scolded for putting everything else under too much pressure. Tuning stuff like disable indexes, have the operations not recoverable and perhaps paralellism (a query hint) are ther too.

Comment: Forgot to add a point.  Both the systems are in LIVE and operational, so updating existing DB object couldn't possible.  We have multiple domains in both the systems and we enable and cutover a domain in new and legacy system.

Answer (score 0):

PLSQL will be always faster by disable the index and constraints .

If you have complex logic spring batch can handle with local partitions or remote paritions based on your logical business objects and increase your hardware configurations or run on different servers with specific logical business objects to improve performance. We have several success experience from file to Database and from database to  database but higher CPU configuration than yours(32 CPU) .

Partition based on Logical business object+reader+writer+hardware configuration+Number of workers plays the role here.